# Apache Felix OSGi error: missing requirement osgi.extender

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix

I'm getting this error when attempting to start a bundle:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
  Unable to resolve com.example.test [7](R 7.0):
    missing requirement [com.example.test [7](R 7.0)] osgi.extender; (&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
  Unresolved requirements:
    [[com.example.test [7](R 7.0)] osgi.extender; (&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>com.example</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Code:

Facade.java:

```
package com.example;
public interface Facade {}
```

FacadeLocator.java:

```
package com.example;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@Component
public class FacadeLocator {
    public static Facade facade;

    @Reference
    public void setFacade(Facade facade) {
        FacadeLocator.facade = facade;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your bundle contains a Declarative Services component -- `FacadeLocator` from your code. This means you have a dependency on the "extender" bundle that implements Declarative Services. You need to deploy that bundle alongside your own bundle in order for it to work.

The DS implementation bundle from Apache Felix has the name `org.apache.felix.scr` and it can be downloaded [from Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.felix%20AND%20a:org.apache.felix.scr&core=gav).

The error message you saw can be decoded as follows. You have a missing requirement in the `osgi.extender` namespace, (the namespace for extenders similar to DS). The specific extender you require is `osgi.component`, version 1.3 or above. The maven-bundle-plugin generated this requirement in your bundle's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF because it saw your bundle has a component in it. Whenever a bundle has a *requirement*, there must be another bundle that provides a matching *capability*. In this case, that bundle is `org.apache.felix.scr`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @MartinHeralecký By the way, saving the service reference into a static field is a really bad idea!

Comment: you can read about similar issue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790543/unresolved-requirement-osgi-component

Answer (score 0):

in karaf install the feature Declarative Service Support by using this cmd
feature:install scr